# What is the correct value of `$?` in a pipeline?

Tags: bash, shell, sh, zsh, ksh

I was a bit disturbed to find the following behavior:

```
bash$ false
bash$ true | echo $?
0
bash$ ksh
ksh$ false
ksh$ true | echo $?
0
ksh$ zsh
zsh$ false
zsh$ true | echo $?
1
```

Intuitively, it looks like zsh gets it right while bash and ksh are wrong.  `$?` is 'the exit status of the most recently executed pipeline', which in each case should be 1.  Note that `false | echo $?` also prints 0 in both `ksh` and `bash`.  Is the standard flexible on this point (ie, the behavior is unspecified), or are `bash` and `ksh` non-compliant here?  I'm also curious to know what bash and ksh are doing to get this wrong.

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin11)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
$ zsh --version
zsh 4.3.11 (i386-apple-darwin11.0)
$ ksh --version
  version         sh (AT&T Research) 1993-12-28 s+
```

Comment: When I ran your `bash` example, I got `1`, not `0`.

Comment: What version of bash? Produces the same as your zsh output on my system.

Comment: Please mention the version of shell please for all. With me `zsh` actually returned `0`. Unable to verify hence.

Comment: That's an ancient collection of shells you have there... looks more like a museum :-)

Comment: On FreeBSD 10.1, `/bin/sh` behaves like `zsh` in your example (`echo` prints "1"). While in `csh`, `... | echo $?` always prints "0".

Comment: `bash` versions 4.1 and 4.3 appear to behave differently with this test, but I haven't drilled into the source to see where/how this changed. FreeBSD's `/bin/sh` is an Almquist shell, so a different beast entirely. Interestingly, FreeBSD's `tcsh` also behaves like older bash (with some extra weirdness), which I agree seems wrong, as I would think that variable expansion should still be done before the command line is executed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/stage7tc1/utilities/V3_chap02.html) says:

> $?
>       Expands to the decimal exit status of the most recent [command or] pipeline ...

Please note the comment from [@lurker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29717388/what-is-the-correct-value-of-in-a-pipeline/29717436?noredirect=1#comment47569312_29717388). Bash in it's current version `4.3.11` behaves the same as `zsh`.

What happens in `bash` and `zsh` is that `$?` will be set by the command *before* the pipe and get not changed inside the pipe. That's why the expected the result is the return value from `false` -> `1`. And this is what POSIX specifies.

I couldn't find any documentation that describes the `ksh` behaviour. I can only assume that `ksh` resets `$?` before executing the pipe, since the following code works:

```
#!/bin/ksh
false
ret=$?
true | echo "$ret"
```

Probably this should get filed as a bug in `ksh`. However, I'm not sure if this behaviour is specified exactly enough by POSIX.

Comment: Yes, so in each case `$?` should be the status returned by `false`.  It should reference the most recent pipeline, and the construction of the pipeline in which it is being used should be irrelevant.

Comment: @hek2mgl Huh? How could `$?` in `echo $?` expand to the exit status of `echo`? It gets evaluated before `echo` runs. Sure, *afterwards*, `echo` will be set to the exit status of `echo` (typically zero), but that's not what the question is about, is it?